# searching a key value in multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

Am totally confused with the multidimensional arrays in php. I have a very big array in which am trying to do some search. That is if the colour is green, check for the age and resultant array should contain 4 highest value of age with colour green and all other subarrays should be unaffected.  Please help

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
     (
        [name] => arr1
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => A
                        [age] => 5
                        [color] => green

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => B
                        [age] => 4
                        [color] => green
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => C
                        [age] => 10
                        [color] => Red
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [name] =>  F
                        [age] => 1
                        [color] => green
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => arr2
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => cc
                        [age] => 8
                        [color] => yellow
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Y
                        [age] => 20
                        [color] => green
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Y
                        [age] => 9
                        [color] => green
                    )
            )

    )
 )
```

Expected resultant array is

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => arr1
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => A
                        [age] => 5
                        [color] => green

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => B
                        [age] => 4
                        [color] => green
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => C
                        [age] => 10
                        [color] => Red
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => arr2
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => cc
                        [age] => 8
                        [color] => yellow
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Y
                        [age] => 20
                        [color] => green
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Y
                        [age] => 9
                        [color] => green
                    )
            )

    )
)
```

Comment: I'm totally confused as to the question

Comment: new array should contain highest value of age whose color is green and all other subarrays inside the main array.

Comment: your reultant array is confusing, can we know what you exactly need? tell us the need in detail

Comment: Here in this case, in the entire array check if the color is green Suppose  If we get green colour more than 5, then check its age. and the resultant array should contain only 4 corresponding values of green with highest age. In the example I had 5 values with green color. Then I checked for age, and displayed the largest 4 ages only.

Comment: you want the highest green values in resultant array?

Comment: 4 highest green values

Comment: but your expected resultant array contains other colors too , that make me confusing

Comment: yeah. this condition is only for green values.

Comment: other colours are unaffected

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Your code here!

$ar[0] = array('name' => 'arr1',
        'data' => array
            (
                '0' => array
                    (
                        'name' => 'A',
                        'age' => 5,
                        'color' => 'green'

                    ),

                '1' => array
                    (
                        'name' => 'B',
                        'age' => 4,
                        'color' => 'green'
                    ),

                '2' => array
                    (
                        'name' => 'C',
                        'age' => 10,
                        'color' => 'Red'
                    ),

                '3' => array
                    (
                        'name' =>  'F',
                        'age' => 1,
                        'color' => 'green'
                    )

            )

    );

$ar[1] = array
    (
        'name' => 'arr2',
        'data' => array
            (
                '0' => array
                    (
                        'name' => 'cc',
                        'age' => 8,
                        'color' => 'yellow'
                    ),

                '1' => array
                    (
                        'name' => 'Y',
                        'age' => 20,
                        'color' => 'green'
                    ),
                '2' => array
                    (
                        'name' => 'Y',
                        'age' => 9,
                        'color' => 'green'
                    )
            )

    );

 $green = array();
 foreach($ar as $k1=>$a1){
     foreach($a1['data'] as $k2=>$a2){
        if($a2['color']=='green') {
            array_push($green,$a2['age']);
        }
    }
 }
 rsort($green);
 $green = array_splice($green,0,4);


 foreach($ar as $k1=>$a1){
     foreach($a1['data'] as $k2=>$a2){
        if($a2['color']=='green') {
            if(!in_array($a2['age'], $green)){
                unset($ar[$k1]['data'][$k2]);
            }
        }
    }
 }
 print_r($ar);
?>
```